# Spring batch - StepExecutionListener

Tags: spring-batch

I am using beforeStep to invoke datasets in my ItemProcessor, can I use StepExecutionListener - beforeStep inside a common function which is not part of ItemProcessor?

Will the beforeStep method work from a common method?

Comment: What do you mean by 'invoke datasets" and "common function"? Maybe you can provide some examples?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my response was too long to add as a comment, so responding as answer.

Thanks for looking into this.  I have a step, which reads from a csv file and writes to DB - table A. I have a processor where I have written the business logic. Now for my business logic, I need to fetch values from table B and table C. To achieve this, I am loading these static tables into a dataset/Map (eg: Map initialize(Collection collection) ) and using them in ItemProcessor via @beforeStep.

My question is, I have multiple steps in my job and it appears I have to hit the db every step to load the same values. I tries moving the business logic along with @beforeStep to another method, but its returning empty values. Is this approach correct or is the @beforeStep tied StepExecutionListener in ItemProcessor (public class A1 implements ItemProcessor, StepExecutionListener {)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this, by creating a bean with util:map for all the dependent static tables and injecting the bean into the processor.